# Using MapFileOutputFormat in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In which version of hadoop can we set.

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(MapFileOutputFormat.class);//ERROR/
```

Basically I have some key value pairs that I want to write in a sorted fashion in a file and then later read them. Is there any way I can use any existing hadoop feature to do this. I do not want to write a map reduce task for it.

Answer (score 1):

In the old API (version 1.x):

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
job.setsetOutputFormat(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapFileOutputFormat.class);
```

In what we call the new API (staring from version 2):

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(conf);
job.setOutputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MapFileOutputFormat.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

See:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapFileOutputFormat.java

It is available since Hadoop 0.20.0. You must be using a version that is greater than that.

Comment: this is not going to work .... the job.setOutputFormatClass(MapFileOutputFormat.class) expects the MapFileOutputFormat class from the mapreduce package not the one from mapred. Other suggestions?